# Updating user supplied params before writing to db in Ecto

Tags: elixir

Here is my User model

```
  @required_fields ~w(name email hashed_password)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ nil) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6)
    |> hash_password(params["password"])
  end

  def hash_password(changeset, password) do
    put_change(changeset, :hashed_password, Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
  end
```

This is the code from the controller

```
changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
```

I'm trying to understand why the validation doesn't pass and I get `hashed_password: "can't be blank"`.

```
%Ecto.Changeset{
  changes: %{
    email: "user@mail.com",
    hashed_password: "$2b$12$6m6nlvykDzvvqgJQswAcxuu96./P2q/ToRRK0mKC//ITp9H6eFeH6",
    name: "user"
  },
  errors: [hashed_password: "can't be blank"]
  ...
 }
```

I see that `hashed_password` was added to `:changes` but where does this error come from then?

Comment: I don't know the parameters didn't match, hash_password function ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're requiring the presence of the `hashed_password` field **before** the field is inserted in the changeset by `hash_password/2`. `cast/4` returns a new changeset with the `"can't be blank"` error since, when it's invoked, the `hashed_password` field *isn't* in the params.

What you may want to do is to replace the `hashed_password` field in the *required* fields with the `password` field. This way, you require that the `password` field is in the parameters passed by the controller.

You don't need to require the `hashed_password` field since you're manually putting it into the changeset, so you're sure it will be there.